# Communication between client (android emulator) and server (app on pc) via java.net.Socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-emulator

I'm writing an simple client-server application, but I have a problem with connecting the client, which is the AVD and server - simple app on PC. When first starts the avd it works ok but when I close the client and server and restart both (server first) the client can't connect to the server. I checked everything I had in mind. I remember to unbind the Service and close Socket when closing Activity, I even tried to change ports automatically using the current system time, because I thought the port is blocked. But nothing changed. To connect again I need to rebuilt the application or restart the avd. I'm affraid I'm searching for bugs in a wrong part of app. Does anybody have a similar problem?

Comment: Post your logcat. Do you have any errors over LogCat.?

Comment: I haven't seen any errors connected with sockets. [Here](http://pastebin.com/urBk1zEM) is a copy of the logcat with my comments on log messages added by me in code.

Comment: I have several applications and never get that situation. The emulator always connects. But since the port you used is not fixed one thing you can do is to use, in a cmd console, the command "netstat -ab" and see what port your app is listening.

Comment: Post your code... that may help.. Paste the code with description of the classes.. I am doing the same thing.!

Comment: Ok Finally I solved a problem. The Service was still running, even after unbiding it from Activity (or mainly because of that). Thanks for help anyway